# Low Level Singleton Instance

Tags: objective-c, singleton, grand-central-dispatch

Can someone give a low level explanation as to why singletonInstance is not set to nil, and how dispatch_one works with the onceToken?

```
+ (id)singletonInstance {
    static FOO *singletonInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        singletonInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return singletonInstance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `singletonInstance` variable *is* set to `nil`, but because it has a `static` scope (i.e. it behaves like a global that is only accessible within this method), it is set to `nil` only once (not every time this method is called). So, once the `singletonInstance` is set to a particular instance of this class inside that `dispatch_once` block, you can rest assured that the variable will not be reset to `nil` later.

The `dispatch_once` call simply ensures that the block of code is called once and only once (and the `static` variable, `onceToken`, is how it keeps track of whether it has been called yet). The benefit of the `dispatch_once` pattern, as opposed to other approaches, is that it's thread-safe (so even if multiple threads try to call `singletonInstance` at the same time, it will only get called precisely once, avoiding race conditions).

The common thread here is the use of `static` keyword in the variable declarations. The `static` qualifier specifies that the variable is not a local variable unique to the particular method, nor is it an instance variable, unique to a particular instance of the class. It is a variable that is effectively shared amongst all calls to this `singletonInstance` method (or, at least until the app is terminated). Thus `static` variables are an effective mechanism to keep track of the singleton instance as well as being a good reference that `dispatch_once` can use to keep track of whether it has been called or not.